# What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x$?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, wolfram-alpha

What is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x$$

?

I always thought it was *undefined*; however, [Wolfram|Alpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limes+x-%3Einfinity+sin+x) that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x = -1 \text{ to } 1$$

Now, what is the correct answer?
What does it even mean if the limit is not a single, distinct value, but rather an interval?

---

Other than that, am I right in assuming that

$$\liminf_{x\to\infty} \sin x = -1$$

and

$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \sin x = 1$$
?

Comment: They mean that the values of $\sin(x)$ for $x\to+\infty$ accumulate to every value in $[-1,1]$. In particular, that implies the $\limsup$, $\liminf$ equations that you wrote, and that in the context of an introduction to calculus, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @arugula so is it in fact undefined?

Comment: Who knows what Alpha means, but I guess you could interpret it as "for every point $p$ between -1 and 1, there's a sequence tending to infinity, such that $\sin$ of that sequence is constantly $p$". And yes you're right about the sup and inf limits.

Comment: To find what Wolfram Alpha means may be difficult?  But presumably this is the same answer as Mathematica itself, which does have extensive documentation you can look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note that the sine function takes values between $-1$ and $1$. When you are talking about a limit to $\infty$, it's an undetermined number, which is infinitely large. Now, taking into account the periodicity of the sine function, there is no possible way to determine a specific value, as it entirely depends on the nature of the "infinite" number.

More specifically, $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1, \; \; \forall x \in \mathbb R$. This means that for any given $x$ over the real numbers, the sine function is bounded. Thus, all you can say about an undetermined infinite limit (it does not exist talking strictly mathematics), is :

$$-1 \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x) \leq 1$$

What you mentioned though is indeed true :

$$\liminf_{x\to\infty} \sin x = -1$$

$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \sin x = 1$$

Comment: So it can be understood as *"the limit doesn't exist, but **if it existed** it would be between -1 and 1"*, right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The limit **does not** exist, but it surely is bounded.

Comment: alright, thank you. I will accept your answer as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 4):

The limit doesn't exist and it can be proved formally by 2 subsequences with different limits, that is

- $x_n=2n\pi+\frac{\pi}2 \to \infty \implies \sin(x_n)=1$
- $x_n=2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}2 \to \infty \implies \sin(x_n)=-1$

Yes what is true is that $\liminf=-1$ and $\limsup=1$ indeed

$$-1\le\sin x \le 1$$

and we have found 2 subsequences which tends to those limits.

Comment: Thank you for the proof as well. Your answer is very good, but I promised Rebellos to accept his answer earlier, so I am sorry. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow You are welcome! The choice of the answer to be accepted is absolutely up to you! Bye